# Alamofire 5.0 with AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator 2.4

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to use alamofire and AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator, but at pod install(both latest versions) i get this:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Alamofire":
  In Podfile:
    Alamofire (~> 5.0)

    AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator (~> 2.4) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
      Alamofire (~> 4.8)
```

I don't want to downgrade alamofire to 4.8 as it will screw with code i already have written.
Am i doing smth wrong or i should just wait for AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator to receive an update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [latest version](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator/tree/3.0.0-beta.3) for your pod linking of AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator (`~> 3.0`)

Comment: AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator 3.0.0 has now been released!